# Why the download traffic towards my IP address is so slow? How to solve it?

Tags: networking, router, dns, performance, traffic

This question has a lot of context and details so please read to the end! I need an answer that will guide me to solving my paradoxical problem.

I've seen people asking questions about slow speeds/traffic and so on, and the answers are "it can be the issue with 1, 2, 3 and whatever", but my situation is highly specific and those general answers seem to be contradictory with what my weird scenario is.

I have a stable internet connection around 30 megabits per second download, and upload speed is often a bit higher or equal.  For somebody, it's a pathetic number but for me it's A LOT! It's a fantastic speed! I can talk to different people around the world with a stable voice conversation and video and demonstration of the screen altogether, all flawless without any lag! All day long!  The problem is with something different and is absolutely terrible:

Fact: My friend (he lives in a nearby country) starts downloading a file at 10 megabytes per second speed from a regular website. Alright. I start downloading a file from that very website, BUT, the speed is at **consistent 40 KILOBYTES per second**! File of a couple gigabytes would take AGES to complete downloading.  It's not just "slower than expected", it's LITERALLY 100 TIMES SLOWER than what i pay ISP for!! (to have at least 3 megabytes per second speed)

it wouldn't be a problem if it's just a single domain, a single website, the problem is that it's pretty much EVERYWHERE. Downloading from almost ALL websites is at 40kilobytes per second!  being it from a developer forums, from a mod community website to download a mod for a game, or any file exchangers, any websites to download assets, textures, audio, texts, documents, MOST of all those websites will deliver files at consistently miserable speeds, **around 40 to 70 kilobytes per second, which is around 100 times slower than the speed given by ISP and speedtest.net**

Logically, the website is NOT slow by itself, because my friend successfully loads and downloads everything he needs as expected.   it would be fine if it's just 2 or 3 times slower, but NOT THAT much!

It will sound like a joke because it's stupidly unbelievable. But it's the truth. The way i download files now, is telling my friend to download a file and then send it to me through Telegram. And it's literally **FASTER than downloading it myself**!!
It's like a weird triangle where one side of the triangle is much longer than the sum of all other sides of the triangle. WHY?? And how to solve it?

```
Website → me   =  100 times slower
Website → my friend → Telegram → me  =  100 times faster
```

Other answers about slow traffic etc seem to talk about "maybe the destination is far away and it's on the other continent or something", but it contradicts with my evidence. In my case, for whatever reason, **Bigger distance is literally faster than the shorter one.**

But it's still not the whole story. To this point, you could say that those websites don't like my IP address for whatever reason. but what about my friends who want to connect to my computer directly? Just directly to my ip address. Without dealing with any third-party domains. Yes, i have a public available unique routed IP address and i can successfuly host an application for others to connect to my computer. It's not a business, it's the friendship. We all have an available internet bandwidth and ready to use all of it to communicate with each other. like for example i've built a beefy chat app with the features my friends would love the most!

There was a cloud service for me to host a live application for my friends but that cloud service is no longer free. it's understandable, and now i can (and have to) use my own computer to host everything. It's going to be faster because it's a direct connection without any far third-party service in-between.
Wrong.

For whatever reason, in the same application with **no software bottlenecks, going through the third-party server was Faster than the direct connection!**

[image of that triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBGHi.png)

Yet again, it's the "paradoxical" triangle.

That is absolutely counterintuitive and very depressing. When i have a will to use my computer, my electricity, my internet  to do something for my friends, why is there such a problem?? I cannot accept paying to some dirty foreign cloud company when my goal is not even any profitable business of any sort.   That is disgusting.

So that's it for the context. I don't have any secrets and i can tell any detail if it's necessary. i live in Georgia (Country, not a US state), i can tell my IP address if that helps.  Now the question. How to break that invisible stupid wall? Is there something wrong in my router parameters like DNS addresses and things like that. In the router, i have my primary DNS set to 77.74.44.44, and the secondary to 212.58.96.96. Also what's the difference between them? There's also the "Routing" tab where i can somehow define the way something goes and reaches certain hosts. Other than that i don't know if there's something i can modify that can change this situation. I need help! I need the traffic to move the right way! how to approach such a problem?

Comment: It's quite possibly some bandwidth QoS settings on your router or machine. Another possibility is the route your traffic takes (depending where you're connecting to the traffic would take different routes) has some bottleneck/issue/limit somewhere in it.

Comment: What packet loss do you have to the websites in question? What does speedtest.net  measure when configured to test against a server in a different location (i.e. _not_ at your ISP)?

Comment: You can also try some more details speed test providers (like https://speed.cloudflare.com/) and see what they show you

Comment: Yisroel Tech, speed.cloudflare.com says i have 25.2mbps download speed and 74mbps upload. packet loss 1.6%. latency 2.0ms. it says Network score quality is Good and Great. Thank you so much for your attention! hopefully we'll be able to solve it

Comment: But what does it say for the breakdown (more towards the bottom)? Any particular test is slow?

Comment: Yisroel Tech, i've triple-checked things and hopefully i understood you correctly. the slowest download test was 13megabits per second(for 1MB data). and by the way, i'm testing it in different browsers and the results are consistent enough. Also, by this time i checked the QoS setting and now i know what this setting is. thank you! It was disabled, but i don't think it's relevant because there aren't many devices that use our home internet. at most 2, but even if no other app and no other device uses the internet, that problem doesn't change based on those factors.

Comment: TL;DR, but if you haven't reached out to your ISP, I recommend you do so. you cannot diagnose issues like intermittently low Signal-to-noise on your upstream, but they can. and it does seem odd that speedtest sees you having 3x more upstream capacity than downstream. usually ISPs that provide asymmetric bandwidth do the opposite.

Comment: Frank Thomas, the more i think about this problem, the more i come to realize that the only one who is able to do something about this problem is my ISP, because it's very obvious it's the issue with routes the traffic takes, and it's getting increasingly obvious that i cannot do anything about it myself. i will contact them and, if necessary, come to their office, and after that i will write here what results i have. thank you again for your attention!

Comment: You can also try a VPN or something like it and see if it helps (which will show that the traffic is slowed/throttled based on content type, since when you have a VPN they don't see the specific type per download or connection.)

Comment: News! using bandwidthplace.com and myspeedmeter.net, i've tested the speed with worldwide servers. and Holy God! In so many places, be it Asia, America,Europe, my download speed doesn't exceed 0.5mbps! And surprisingly for Frank Thomas, the upload speed is not just 3x, it's 90x higherXDD. it's like 40mbps!  Yisroel Tech, i have the evidence that download speed depends on address/domain/IP of the website and not content type so we can be sure it's not that. i'm paying a LOT to ISP, and it's totally unacceptable to have nothing more than 0.5mbps! ISP told me they'll contact me so i'm on the way.

Comment: Still, for new people trying to add something here, don't forget the context that *some* addresses like Telegram and Youtube (and some others), they work at nearly full speeds: 40mbps download,  whereas almost anything else is so incredibly sluggish. And by the way, i live in the capital of Georgia. it's not like some village with connection problems.  Anyway guys, i appreciate all you're trying to do! At least it will be a fun story of how much of a weird problem can occur to a person. Love you!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question won't be answered if i don't do it myself. so here i have a (hopefully temporary) very sad answer: "there's just nothing to do with it".

Understanding that probably the only one who has enough control to deal with the problem is ISP, so here i've just contacted my ISP and guess what they told me? They told me "connecting you to the world is not our problem". Yeah, literally...
And they said they give me the proper local speed and they don't care about how my internet reaches the world... I'm depressed right now i don't know where to find any help. Living in a poor family and paying more than all taxes combined to get like 0.3mbps speed worldwide on average. that is just depressing guys i wanna cry. ISP is not even willing to investigate anything or check anything or give any information, no matter what i'm saying. all they said is that no other ISP does better.  it's enormous just how disappointed i am in my country.
So for now it seems an answer is that sometimes you're born not in the right place and there's nothing to do with it.
but i always have a place for hope. sorry for asking for help, but it's because i hope there might be a different answer! if somebody has more detailed ideas and questions to help, here's my discord: Alekochachua#7253. if i find a way to overcome this problem, i promise i'll write a new answer here. I'm grateful to you people for letting me post a question on this forum. thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).